# Is it possible to expose a DateTime field through COM?

Tags: c#, com, serialization

it looks like that I am not able to expose via COM a class to an unmanaged client if one of the property of the class has type `DateTime` .

Example:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface ITest
{
   string Name { get; }
   DateTime Date { get; }
}

[Serializable]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class Test : ITest
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; private set; }
}
```

Only if I comment out the `Date` property on both the interface and implementation will the .tlh file contain a the Test structure (obviously without the `Date`).

Any idea? Is there a way to represent a date that is visible via COM? Do I really need to pass the `Date` as a `string` and then parse it?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In COM, a Date is a Variant of type VT_DATE. I think you can make use of this:
http://blogs.msdn.com/dimeby8/archive/2006/12/12/marshalling-variant-properties-in-c.aspx